# EJB Transaction not Committed unless invoking EntityManger#flush()

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.1, jta, jboss6.x, flush

My application uses Hibernate as JPA provider and JBOSS 6.1.0-final as server. And the transaction is CMT (Transaction type in my persistence.xml is JTA). As most tutorial suggests. transaction in a ejb method will be automatically committed if it ends without any exception. However, in my application, unless I use `flush()`, the transaction won't be committed when ejb method ends successfully(e.g. inserting a record never push any data to the database). It is the same result in both stateless and stateful beans.

I try to use `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)`, but the result is also the same. Even using `MANDATORY` annotation doesn't throw any exception, which suggest my ejb method is using a container managed transaction.

Code Fragement:

```
 @Stateful
 @Local
 public class TransactionTest implements ITransactionTest {

   @PersistenceContext(unitName="Table")
   private EntityManager manager;

   public void generateRecord(int i) throws RuntimeException{
     Record record = new Record();
     record.setId(i+"");
     record.setStatus(1);
     manager.persist(record);
     manager.flush();  //without this, it won't commit
  }
}
```

So, why my ejb method can't commit transaction automatically?

Comment: Can you update your post with relevant code.

Comment: I add a sample code here.

Answer (score 1):

Stateful session bean has `PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED` by default.

> **5.6.1.2 Container-managed Extended Persistence Context**
>
> A container-managed extended persistence context exists from the point
>   at which the container-managed entity manager has been obtained by
>   dependency injection or through JNDI lookup until it is closed by the
>   container. Such an extended persistence context can only be initiated
>   within the scope of a stateful session bean and is closed by the
>   container when the @Remove method of the stateful session bean
>   completes (or the stateful session bean instance is otherwise
>   destroyed).
>
> When an extended persistence context is used, the entities
>   managed by the EntityManager remain managed independently of whether
>   JTA transactions are begun or committed. They do not become detached
>   until the persistence context ends.

- You can try `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW`, therefore commit is called after exiting from the method. Flush automatically gets called before commit.

  If you want to commit changes right away, you can try changing the transaction attribute, which will be part of a separate new transaction.
- If you don't want to commit changes & needs single transaction to propagate , then your current approach is fine & call flush explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried your method, both using `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW` and statless beans. But none of them work. Is there any other point to be noticed?

Comment: @Kajelas Did you tried (stateless+REQUIRES_NEW) or (stateful+REQUIRES_NEW).